# Any potential security risk when exposing ActiveMQ web console in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, activemq-classic

I was unable to access the ActiveMQ web console in 5.16 version.
I opened the required ports in AWS security group and I checked which ports are configured for console and the broker URL, yet the browser said "Page Not Found" so I looked into the `jetty.xml` and noticed this line:

```xml
<bean id="jettyPort" class="org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsolePort" init-method="start">
    <!-- the default port number for the web console -->
    <property name="host" value="127.0.0.1"/>
    <property name="port" value="8161"/>
 </bean>
```

I changed the `host` to `0.0.0.0`:

```xml
<bean id="jettyPort" class="org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsolePort" init-method="start">
    <!-- the default port number for the web console -->
    <property name="host" value="0.0.0.0"/>
    <property name="port" value="8161"/>
</bean>
```

Now I am able to access the web console. However does this give any security risk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *always* inherently more risk when exposing additional points of entry into a system (e.g. a management console).

The ActiveMQ web console is a powerful tool which can be used to delete messages, remove destinations, stop the broker, etc. If a user gains unauthorized access to the web console then they can make a real mess. If you expose the web console to external users then be sure to secure it according to [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/web-console).